# nested divs should have 2 diff css styles

Tags: css

I have 2 nested divs, both have

```
#x{
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:#fff;
color:#000
}

#y{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#000;
color:#ccc;
}


<div id="y"><div id="x">Here lies a x value</div></div>
```

I want the #x and #y to have individual css properties, but that is not the case, #x overrides the #y values

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You have two #y classes. Is that what you intended?

Comment: sorry done editing that was #x and #y

Comment: Your nested div is wider than the parent.

Comment: @kyle yes, I need to have 2 boxes, each with diff styles

Comment: Your `width` declarations miss the dimension: `width:200px` would do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

```
#y{
width:400px;<-- add px.
height:400px;
background-color:#fff;
color:#000
}

#x{ <--changed to X, it was y
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#000;
color:#ccc;
}
```

Also, when you `id` a `div` to `x` it will take the properties you detup in `#x`.

Comment: I know it will take the properties of #x, but I want the divs to have individual properties, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, just set it up in the CSS, that's what it's for. You have it right, if you want to have more different styles, eg `border` then tell `#x` or `#y` to have a border and it will, but the other won't. You need to tell nested divs each and every different thing you want, or as far as I know it will inherit from its parent on most properties.

Answer (score 0):

They do have individual properties.  It is just that the nested x div is in front of the y div, so the y div is obscured.  Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to #y and you will see that it constrains #x to it's footprint.

Comment: The white div background blends in with the white page background.  Try applying a border to #x to see its bounds. Or change the page background to yellow. You could also apply a top and left margin to #x to see some of #y exposed. Here is a sample: http://test.kingdesk.com/nested-widths.html As you will see, #y maintains it's styling (behind #x)

Answer (score -1):

Specificity!  As your two declarations have the same specificity, the one that comes last in the CSS is the one that is honoured.  To increase the specificity of the inner target, try:

```
#y #x{
width:400;
height:400px;
background-color:#fff;
color:#000
}

#y{
width:200;
height:200px;
background-color:#000;
color:#ccc;
}
```

[Here's a cracking article on the subject](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).

Comment: I doubt that specifity has to do *anything* with it. The declaration for one div with ID `x` is *never* applied to another div with ID `y` (not counting the case of inheritance, as is the case with the `color` property, but the question IMHO is targeted to the dimensions)

Comment: its not targeted to border or dimensions, but color also. Assume I have opacity in #y and my div setting is as <div id=y><div id=x></div></div>.  But I dont want a opacity change in #x

Comment: @Jean: In that case, follow either graphicdivine's approach or change the order of the CSS declarations. Latter ones overwrite earlier ones with the same specifity.

Comment: The -1 is new, isn't it? I wonder why, since the answer at least explains, why the `color` is different.